# Background video from Youtube doesn't start while in mobile resolution

Tags: html, css, mobile, youtube, adaptive-design

I used CSS and Youtube IFrame to make a background-video, but it doesn't start after I switch to mobile resolution (using F12 etc.).

[Screenshot from Chrome, it is the same on mobile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm1pa.png)

[GitHub repo with my code.](https://github.com/Tarasovych/test)

```
<div class="video-background">
  <div class="video-foreground">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W0LHTWG-UmQ?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Most mobile phones don't actually support mobile autoplay, if that's what this was regarding? Have I misunderstood?

Comment: ah, thanks, you've understood me. so, maybe it's possible to hide youtube play button?

Comment: I have submitted an answer to the question in which contains the instructions on how to hide the youtube iframe's play button

Comment: or maybe I'd download video and run it from pc?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile phones don't support autoplay bg-video. So i used to set an img while on mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no way to autoplay a video on most mobile devices at the moment. This is actually in regards to the bandwidth of phones being used up.

I have found these params in which you can use to hide the play button as discussed in the comments. These are:

`showinfo=0
controls=0
autohide=1`

So this would make the full url: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/W0LHTWG-UmQ?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ&showinfo=0&controls=0&autohide=1`

Comment: ah, it still doesn't work. I'll try another way maybe

Comment: The hiding of the play button? I have added this to a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vutaphxq/ and seems to be working fine

Comment: May I ask which device / browser you are using?

Comment: chrome, also I use mobile previev in it

Comment: This seems to be an issue with mobile not supporting the removing of the play button. You can see that this jsfiddle does indeed work on chrome desktop.